# What happens if an entire continent is evaporated?

Tags: earth, natural-disasters

Suppose that a continent on planet Earth is entirely evaporated in an instant - including all that lives on it at that particular moment (birds which flew over it at the time of its evaporation were saved, for that matter).

Also suppose that the continent's borders are very well drawn, and that only that particular continent is destroyed.

What would happen in the years and decades that follow the evaporation of that continent? I am only interested in "natural events" such as tsunamis, climate changes, movement of the other continents, etc. and not in the social/economic impact of having one continent less to trade with.

Comment: How far down, all the way through the Earth's crust? In the case it's just down to sea-level, you're talking an extinction-level event for complex life, if through the crust, not even the bacteria deep beneath the Earth on the opposite side would stand much of a chance. Perhaps instead of asking us this rather random question, you might tell us what you're aiming for - then we can help you to get there.

Comment: "Evaporated" has a specific meaning (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaporation); the former continent and its contents has now turned into a very, very hot gas.  For example, many of the constituents of lava have boiling points of around 3,000 Celsius.  So, a continent-size shockwave of hot gas envelops the planet, scouring all life from the surface and possibly boiling the oceans to some modest depth.

Comment: @GrumpyYoungMan: And a significant portion of that very hot gas will go up into space (but not quite at escape velocity), where it will condense and either form another small moon, or rain down on the rest of the planet.  See e.g. tectites and the iridium-enriched layer deposited by the Chicxulub impact.

Comment: It all depends on how deep the "evaporation" goes. One millimeter deep, nothing much happens elsewhere in the world. All the 30 km deep continental crust, well, that's a very very large amount of thermal energy -- large enough to sterilize all the other continents and the top few hundred meters of the ocean.

Comment: We definitely need a better definition of what is happening, since a lot of what a continent "is" consists of structures deep underground. Also define what happens to the matter "evaporated" (I suspect you're talking more dematerialized, or possibly displaced with air). Most of these scenarios will look like a Permian extinction event up to breakup of the planetary crust. Bad.

Comment: This question does a good job defining the parameters of a similar but opposite event. https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/66412/what-would-be-the-immediate-climatic-effects-of-having-a-continent-appear-out-of?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Almost everybody dies.

The "evaporation" of a continent's surface must be at the very least a couple of inches deep, or most of everything will remain more or less unscathed.

This means something in the neigbourhood of ten or twenty million square kilometers - that's about one million *million* cubic meters of matter, or about two million million tons of mostly organic matter and aluminum silicates (i.e., dirt), plus a considerable quantity of sulfur compounds.

As soon as the "evaporation" stops, even without factoring in the energy that must have gone *into* that evaporation, or the temperatures possibly involved - which would trigger a colossal firestorm - you've got a gazillion cubic *kilometers* of fine particulates that will start burning, consuming a significant percentage of Earth's athmospheric oxygen in the process. Also, the heat release will be more than enough to propel a lot of fine particulates and sulfur dioxide into the lower stratosphere, and the temperatures will be high enough to lock a lot of oxygen in toxic nitrogen oxides and carbon monoxide.

The Chicxulub event is variously estimated to have lifted 300 to 500 cubic kilometers of pulverized crust; the [nuclear winter](https://gizmodo.com/dinosaur-killing-asteroid-basically-brought-a-nuclear-w-1820048402) might have lasted from 20 to 50 years.. The Toba Event scores at around 3000 and came *this* close to ending the human race. Here, we are around 30% of a Toba Event (but still twice the one that killed off the dinosaurs), but the atmospheric damage looks orders of magnitude higher.

Also, the phenomenon starts already spread *way* out, over a whole continent by definition; the affected area *starts* at 10 to 20 millions of square kilometers, 2% at least of the total land area.

Between the oxygen depletion, the poisonous gases and the nuclear winter caused by the atmospheric dust, I expect the environment to become unable to sustain most modern terrestrial life-forms, man included, unless a lot of technology is brought to bear (filters, oxygen concentrators, electric-lamp greenhouses, water purification, and so on).

*Will* there be time for some people to prepare enough as to bootstrap into such a setup? (which means finding a reasonably safe and viable place, preparing to scavenge matériels to build an arcology, and *building* the arcology; then surviving - not just physically but culturally, genetically and technologically - at least fifty to one hundred years until conditions improve enough for algae and some plant life to resurface and atmospheric oxygen to start climbing again, so that oxygen concentrators are the only thing you still need - probably for the next several centuries).

Maybe.

Maybe not. In this latter case, *everybody* dies.

## "Evaporation" as in, vanish.

This depends on the depth of the vashing effect.

- up to several tens of meters: nothing much happens immediately, isostatic equilibrium is restored eventually, very likely some weather impact due to the sudden replacement of a biosphere with what is essentially naked rock. The planet overall is unaffected and so, I expect, is civilization (once the worldwide panic and unrest quieten). Depending on the continent involved, there is a chance of World War III breaking out due to panic, accident, or both.
- up to two-three kilometers: the isostatic equilibrium is broken too much, resulting in a massive sequence of earthquakes. Almost certainly, whatever the continent, the nearby seas and oceans pour in the hole, creating a new ocean and changing the coastlines everywhere else (*massive* weather impact). Earth's albedo is probably increased, and this might cause a cooling in the following centuries. All the problems of case 1, above, apply.
- *more* than a few kilometers: planet-wide earthquakes and general volcanogenic activity, but also massive fracturing of the Earth surface and release of massive quantities of sulfur compounds, ashes and gases. Water falls into the caldera and is turned into water vapour on an unprecedented scale. Nuclear winter and mass extinctions on the scale of the Chicxulub impact, but probably far worse (the Chicxulub caldera closed in a matter of hours. A *continent-wide* caldera is going to take *years*).

Comment: @ARogueAnt. I've kept to about five centimeters' depth, and used values for Europe. I had considered what would happen with soil versus rock, but basically I believe both to be just as bad, in somewhat different ways. However, with that thickness I believe the vaporized matter would be almost only soil, sand and clays.

Comment: It really jump in answer. OP didn't specify, and it should have been asked - what he means by evaporation. My impression OP talks about vanish like a mirage, beamed away or all kind of such stuff. Jumping in assumption of heat induced evaporation - there is no way birds flying over to be spared in such case. So there are contradictions which should have been solved first. And my impression the q is typical whatif scenario, which does not consider realism of how the initial cause was produced.

Comment: @MolbOrg this is true. Amending answer.

Comment: By looks of it OP didn't care as long as it anything, or you may guessed, but just for the future